# How can i insert the json objects into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, json

I have json objects like

```
    {
"taskman":[
   {
   "Index":"9",
   "Uid":"a",
   "Pswd":"123",
   "Name":"sahana",
   "Doj":"01-08-2014",
   "Project":
      {
      "Pid":"1",
      "Pname":"logger",
      "Start_date":"12-08-2014",
      "Desc":"previous logs",
      "task":
        {
        "Tid":"1",
        "Tname":"login",
        "Tstart_date":"16-08-2014",
        "Tstart_time":"10/40/30",
        "Tstatus":"10%"
        },
      "Status":"5%"
      },
    "Last_Update":"22-08-2014"
   },
   {
   "Index":"9",
   "Uid":"aa",
   "Pswd":"123",
   "Name":"sahana",
   "Doj":"01-08-2014",
   "Project":
      {
      "Pid":"1",
      "Pname":"logger",
      "Start_date":"12-08-2014",
      "Desc":"previous logs",
      "task":
        {
        "Tid":"1",
        "Tname":"login",
        "Tstart_date":"16-08-2014",
        "Tstart_time":"10/40/30",
        "Tstatus":"10%"
        },
      "Status":"5%"
      },
    "Last_Update":"22-08-2014"
   }

 ] 
}
```

How can i decode the json objects and then after decoding how can i insert data into table called "taskman" using php, what is the structure of taskman table i.e,column and their datatype.

Comment: have you searched google. here is a documentation about decoding [json](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)